# Possible to start an application without a GUI but show GUI if required?

Tags: vb.net

I have a small application that monitors an external executable to ensure that it is running/perform upgrades, etc.  This application has to run all the time, however, I need it to run semi-invisible to the user.

By this I mean that when the application first launches, it has not GUI (runs as a process but has no interface to the user).  However, if required, the user can launch the application again which will bring up the GUI so they can see what's going on.

I already run the external executable in the system tray, so I didn't really want to create two icons in the system tray for the one thing if possible.  I would much prefer this utility to just run in the background until needed.

I can start the application minimized and set ShowInTaskbar = false but I then don't know how to access the GUI if required.

Is this possible?  Or can someone suggest a method of achieving this?  Do I need to create another exe to simply set the window state back to normal?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You can play with the transparency of the form. Put it to 100% transparent

Comment: what will monitor your application?

Comment: You can make your application to run as a single instance. When you try to run the application the second time this will be detected and you can set the Form to be visible. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/11/01/simplify-application-instancing.aspx

Comment: If you turn off the "Application Framework" in the project settings, you will have full control over when `Application.Run` gets called, how often it get's called, and under which circumstances.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I am not sure how is this exactly related to the OP's request of starting the application hidden. I have proposed what I think that is the only way to accomplish that (other than changing its transparency as proposed in the comment above). I guess that saying Me.Visible = True/False is pretty close to having full control; what alternative are you proposing?

Comment: @varocarbas, Presumably, if he doesn't want to show a GUI, he still wants to do something else instead.  I'm just proposing that in that situation, he just do whatever that other thing is, from the `Sub Main`, *instead* of calling `Application.Run`.  It's not clear, though, whether or not whatever he's doing without a GUI still requires a message loop.  If so, that changes things, but I just thought it would be helpful information to open up some options in either case.

Comment: @StevenDoggart OK. Clearer now. What he might want is hiding the form until an external event occurs (for example: the contents of a file change); he can be checking the condition to be met via Timer. This is what I understood from the original requirements.

Comment: Why would you need two icons in the system tray?  Just have a menu on the single icon and add a menu item to launch the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Visible = False
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
End Sub
```

You can make it visible again by setting the two aforementioned properties to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a NotifyIcon and show your GUI for ex. on a doubleclick. You can even use the icon as a status indicator. To hide it on start use this one: [***varocarbas answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999815/possible-to-start-an-application-without-a-gui-but-show-gui-if-required/19000319#19000319) and to show just set me.visisble to true.

I just think a NotifyIcon is better than starting the exe a second time to show the gui.

Comment: The OP said "I didn't really want to create two icons in the system tray for the one thing if possible". In any case you are not saying how to hide the form.

Comment: Yes, he said IF possible ;)